# how to upload bulk data in fusion table

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I want to import bulk data into fusion table . What is the best data format should I use to import data i.e JSON ,CSV .

If I want to import data in JSON format how can I do it since on google help only way was to upload CSV files .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Supported formats for upload through the Fusion Tables UI](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171181/?&) are:

- comma-separated text (.csv)
- other text-delimited files (.tsv, etc)
- KML (.kml)
- spreadsheets (.xls, .xslx, .ods and Google Spreadsheets), given the Google Docs limits.

If you write your own application, you can upload data using the [Fusion Tables API v1](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide), but I wouldn't call that a "bulk import" as there are smaller limits.

Comment: hi geocodezip ...Can you help me with sample code for data upload in java . I am new to fusion table and tried a piece of code but am getting unauthorized error !!!

Comment: I am not really a java developer.  You could look at the example [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code), but the only java sample I see there is for the deprecated SQL API (but I would think the authorization part would be the same).